# How do use Host Headers in IIS 6.0?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, iis, web-hosting

I want to resolve a SharePoint site collection running on port 33425 to http://SITENAME/.

I have a server 2003, sp2 hosting Web sites, some using SharePoint. I have DNS set up to point to the IP address of the server. Ping returns success when I enter SITENAME. I get Under Construction when I enter http://SITENAME/ in a browser.

I have tried setting Host Headers with this port and name, SITENAME, on the default Web site on port 80 and on the the site running on 33425. What should I do to get this to resolve correctly? I have tried the directions given on this link in MSDN  [Using Host Header Names to Host Multiple Web Sites (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/883a9544-3f70-4d46-a6df-bbadbd1fe7de.mspx?mfr=true)
. I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to some of the links I had read previously, and found that this one [Setting Host Headers in IIS 6.0](http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/) was actually telling me what I needed. That is I needed to go to the Properties dialog of my site assigned to port 33425 and ADD a port 80 entry with the alias, SITENAME. I had tried making the opposite changes to the default site, and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With our Sharepoint we have a CNAME record which resolves the SITENAME. This may well have been setup automatically, but worth looking into in your instance.

Comment: This is SharePoint 2007. How do set the CNAME in SharePoint 3.0 Central Management?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow but you set a CNAME record in your DNS for your internal network.

Comment: DNS was set up for me already. To route a request to the Server's IP address I need DNS. To then resolve that on the Web server to a particular port on the server, I need Host Headers. Thanks.